# Who cares about Transpiled Circuit Text?

Tags: ibm-q-experience, qasm

At any result of a job in this last version of the Circuit Composer, at the OpenQasm tab inside the Circuit Diagram, I am unable  to use the tradicional copy or ctrl-c to get the transpiled circuit selected text for further studies.

**Is this an error or it is functioning correctly, because in before versions it was possible doing it?**

Comment: Martin, then let's wait to be fixed.
Thanks for the tip but if the code has more then 50 lines it will be truncated at the ctrl-v paste..

Answer (score 1):

I think its an error. If you want a poor temporary solution you can try to select the whole box starting at the big title Transpiled Circuit to the last code line. It will copy the line numbers together with the QASM code but I think it will be better than nothing.